# I want to make list of all ipv4 addresses around the globe

Tags: python, performance, networking, optimization, ip

I don't understand networking. I wrote this code but I need a faster solution. Anyone got any ideas? Thank you
Code:

```
for i in range(0, 256):
  for j in range(0, 256):
      for k in range(0, 256):
        for l in range(0, 256):
          print("{}.{}.{}.{}".format(i, j, k, l))
          with open("ip_2.txt", "a") as f:
            f.write("{}.{}.{}.{}\n".format(i, j, k, l))
```

Thanks again.

Comment: This was on /r/ProgrammingHumor recently. Did you copy it from there?

Comment: No, I did not. Just wrote this morning. Could you share the link to post, maybe it can help?

Comment: Your code is trying to write 4 billion addresses to a file. At 1 millisecond per address,  that will take 7 weeks and the file will occupy about 50Gb. There is not a lot you can do to speed that up because it is IO bound. What on earth would you do with such a file anyway, even if you had it?

Comment: It's a joke, simply because it is horribly inefficient and has zero use. You even made it worse by printing it out, now the console becomes the bottleneck.

Comment: And those are IP version 4 addresses. The world ran out of those about a decade ago.

Comment: Guys, one of my clients asked me to do that. Not sure what he's gonna do with that. I just needed to make it. Thanks for your time.

Comment: In your role as a technician, it is sometimes necessary to explain politely to a client that what they have asked for is impossible or pointless. The next thing to do is to ask them to state *the problem to be solved*, rather than ask you to implement *the solution they have dreamed up*. Even if you had such a file, you would have a hard time delivering it. If I set you that problem in an interview, the fact that you even tried to implement it would have me looking for another candidate.

Comment: You are not even taking into account the IPv4 addresses that cannot be used. You should not, for example, list anything in the `0.0.0.0/8`, `127.0.0.0/8`, `224.0.0.0/4`, and `240.0.0.0/4` ranges because they cannot be used for IPv4 addressing. There are other, smaller ranges that also cannot be used. Python is glacially slow, and this is a completely pointless exercise.